# Default Craft entry limit

Tags: entries, limit, default

There seems to be a default limit to `for` loops in craft of `100`.

I have a channel with quite a few entries.

How can I disable this without writing nasty things like `.limit(100000000)`

Comment: Does `.limit(null)` work?

Comment: @user1463467 beat me to it, why not post as a real answer?

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure and didn't want to lose my precious karma (I hate stackexchange with a passion).

Comment: This question applies to Craft 2. As of Craft 3 there is no limit by default.
Source: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#300---2018-04-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Craft 3, there is no limit by default.

Per the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#300---2018-04-04):

> Element queries are no longer limited to 100 results by default.

*(Credit to Ben Croker who originally added this answer as a comment above. Adding this here as it would be better as the upvoted answer.)*

Answer (score 13):

Set the limit to null `limit(null)`.

Comment: This answer applies to Craft 2. As of Craft 3 there is no limit by default so setting `limit` to `null` is not necessary unless trying to override a previously set value.
Source: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#300---2018-04-04

Comment: @BenCroker - glad I wasn't the only one who read the latest Craft Link List and suddenly thought of the Jumanji meme of "What Year is it??" :)

Answer (score 1):

There very definitely is a default limit of 100 and using .limit(null) will definitely override it. I know this because I recently had the same issue myself!