# getPrev and getNext stop working after 100+ entries

Tags: templating, error-message

Prev and Next stop working after 100 entries..  There are no template errors.  I can access the pages for the individual entries - but Next and Previous are blank.

Here is my set up...

`{% set criteria = {section: 'posts'} %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
{% set next = entry.getNext(criteria) %}`

`{% if prev %}`
**`my html ...{{ prev.url }} ...my html`**
`{% endif %}`

The same holds true for next.

Once there was a template error referencing a null value on prev.url - and referencing an entry ID that no longer appears to exists.  However, I discovered that I had had `prev` under `if next`.  That is the only time I was able to produce a template error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your criteria, you need to set the `limit` to `null` as by default Craft only returns up to 100 entries.

See: [Default Craft entry limit](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14453/default-craft-entry-limit)

Comment: Oh wow, I did not realize that came into play here.  I went ahead and added {% set criteria = craft.entries.section('posts').limit(null) %}.  It worked.  Thanks.